# Why does the xcode say "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time..." for my Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an app, and I have a block of code that reads like this:

```
let DestViewController: ftrViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ftrViewController

let weightInt: Int? = Int(weightInKilos.text!)
let dehydrationInt: Int? = Int(percentOfDehydration.text!)
let lossesInt: Int? = Int(ongoingLosses.text!)
let factorFloat: Float? = Float(Factor.text!)

let lrs24Int = (30 * weightInt! + 70) * factorFloat! + weightInt! * dehydrationInt! * 10 + lossesInt!
```

However, Xcode says that `Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`.

My equation looks right to me, and I do not believe that my equation is too complex, because I had the same error when the problem was simply that I wasn't declaring the integers correctly (the deal with the ?s and the !s).

Does anybody see a problem in my code that is leading to this error, or is the expression *truly* too hard for the computer to solve in reasonable time? Thanks!

**PS-** I think the problem might be the float, because before I added the float, it was working fine.

Comment: If you want me to clarify something, just tell me :)

Comment: can you add the brackets in your expression so i can understand it

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by brackets

Comment: Please check the following Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Rewritten Code**

```
let weightInt: Float? = Float(weightInKilos.text!)
let dehydrationInt: Float? = Float(percentOfDehydration.text!)
let lossesInt: Float? = Float(ongoingLosses.text!)
let factorFloat: Float? = Float(Factor.text!)

let step1 = (30 * weightInt! + 70) * factorFloat! + weigh
let lrs24Int = step1 * dehydrationInt! * 10 + lossesInt!
```

It was not Only Float problem. I used float to avoid type conversions as all are float. The Main Problem was the Complexity of expression.

Comment: Wow...I can't believe I didn't think of replacing all the integers with floats :P Sorry I spent your time on this question! I started only this year, so I'm not very good at solving programming problems myself yet :)

Comment: no worries it happens , even i started 7 months ago.

Comment: It was not Only Float problem. I used float to avoid type conversions as all are float. The Main Problem was the Complexity of expression.

Comment: @Sulthan what you expect in explanation.

Comment: I did rate it up, but Sulthan rated down, so it's back to zero.

Comment: What he was expecting as explaination